# Path issue Pip (Psycopg2) inside VirtualEnv

Tags: django, pip, virtualenv, mod-wsgi, psycopg2

When using Pip (6.0.8) to install Django (1.9) and Psycopg2 (2.6.1), Django got installed in the env/lib/python2.7/site-packages folder and Psycopg2 in the env/lib64/python2.7/site-packages folder.

When I'm using command line (eg python manage.py migrate) or >>> import psycopg2, this all works fine. But when Mod_WSGI is running the application it complains that there is no module Psycopg2.

I'm able to work around this issue by adding the lib64 as a python path in my Apache conf file, but I'm pretty sure this is not the best possible way.

Any suggestions for a better solution?

Btw: I noticed by the way that Pip 7.1.2 is installing Django in Lib64 as well iso Lib.

Comment: Can you include your Apache config, as well as your wsgi.py?

Comment: I am also facing this issue. Can you please tell me how did you configure Apache to read lib64 folder inside virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is with the use of `--install-option`. Have a look at [the docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption--install-option)